# Razorpages Post new record and return to page with updated Id

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, I have a form that returns a Person by Id, and allows the user to update the record or add a new Person OnPost.

When posting a new record, I expect it to return to the same page and display the updated Id, but it remains as 0.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FavouriteDoughnut { get; set; }
    }
```

The form:

```
   @page "{personId:int}"
   @model Pages.EditModel

   <form method="post">
      <label asp-for="Person.PersonId">Id</label>
      <input asp-for="Person.PersonId" readonly>

      <label asp-for="Person.Name">Name</label>
      <input asp-for="Person.Name">

      <label asp-for="Person.FavouriteDoughnut">Doughnut?</label>
      <input asp-for="Person.FavouriteDoughnut">

      <button type="submit>Save</button>
   </form>
```

```
  
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public async void OnGet(int personId)
    {
        if(personId > 0)
        {
            Person = await _dbContext.People.FindAsync(personId);

            return;
        }
            Person = new Person();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        Person = UpdatePerson(Person);
    }

    private void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        _dbContext.People.Update(person);
        await _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return person;
    }
```

Do I need to redirect to the Edit page? When I inspect the Person OnPost I can see that it is updated and the page refreshes, it just doesn't get populated with the new Id.

Comment: Do you want the Id updated on the URL? If that's the case I would suggest you redirect `RedirectToPage("/PageName", new{ personId = Person.Id }` in your `OnPost` method.

Comment: @MosiaThabo yes, that's acceptable. Mostly, I'm wondering why the field on the form isn't updating with the new ID after post. I don't mind Redirect if that's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your model design, `PersonId` is the `PrimaryKey` in database, when user post a new record, The value of `PersonId` is self-incrementing rather than depending on the value of the `PersonId` in the new record. When user want to post a new record, The input box of `PersonId` will be automatically locked, Not allowing  user to enter anything, So the page will not receive the value of `PersonId`, after the page refresh, It will not display the real value of `PersonId`.

In my opinion, Showing the primary key to the user is not necessary, But if you want to do that, You can query by `PersonId`  and return the result to the page after adding the new record or just `RedirectToPage("/Edit", new{ personId = Person.Id }`, I recommend you to use the second method.

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't PersonId needs to be present on the form since the entity is not tracked?  

When we resubmit the same form, with edits, as I currrently have it, it creates a new record since the Id has not been populated on the form. Why doesn't the page update with the new Id? I'd like to understand. It is a primary key, identity column, in the Db and identified in the DbContext.

Comment: Did you find that the `personid` input box is automatically locked whether you update or add record? You can only enter something in `Name` and `FavouriteDoughnut`. But the different is when you update record, The value of  `personId` will be automatically filled into the input box, So when you submit the form, The page can receive the value of `personid` and display it.

Comment: But when you add a new record, The value of `personid` is only automatically generated when it is added to the database ,So It is null in current page, when you submit the form, page will not receive the value, So it can't dispaly the value of personId.  Because you can't change the value of personid in page, So i think it is meaningless to show this property in your form.